# ReportDocument.ExportToDisk() takes too long

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, export

I am doing unit testing and I noticed the program never finishes executing the line

```
var reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
reportDoc.Load("M:\ArchiveNodeAccessReport.rpt");
reportDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", ".", "MyDB");
for (int i = 0; i < reportDoc.Database.Tables.Count; i++) {
            reportDoc.Database.Tables[i].ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
        }
reportDoc.VerifyDatabase();
reportDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "M:\Report.pdf");
```

What might be causing this problem and how may I work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific what is reportDoc of what Type are you Referencing this ..Also what type of file extension are you exporting to .doc, .rtf, etc

Comment: If the report is pulling from a sql database, run the query by itself and see if that's part of the hold up. Could be a query timeout.

Comment: where is your coded portion where are you creating the Stream..?

Comment: Look at this link it shows examples on how to do PDF but the site does it via Http web response. If this makes sense I am sure you can easily convert the 1 to 2 lines to fit your example 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17950/How-to-export-a-Crystal-Report-using-C

Comment: can you show more code too..? where is the code where you are calling the .Export(); method assuming that this is crystal reports

Comment: I am debugging an issue (and I suspect HIPS/HBSS monkeying around) similar to this. I have a development machine, PDF prints instantly. I have a local IIS7 Win7 box -- PDF Prints instantly, on my production IIS7, the report never times out and never finishes. SQL Query in Profiler runs and exits near instantly...